# Spring MVC отправка письма в другом потоке

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring-mvc, инспекция-кода

Добрый день! Есть задача, с веба отправлять на почту письма с вложениями. Проблема в том, что вложения могут быть около 20мб., и если юзер жмет кнопку отправить то он должен ждать пару мин, пока файл отправляется. Поэтому решил сделать в другом потоке отправку, т.е. просто стартануть, а юзеру сделать редирект типо все ОК.
Подскажите, верно ли это реализовано? Пробовал паралельно отправлять с 2 компов, сразу по 3-4 файла, все вроде приходит корректно. Важно понимать, что если 10 человек , вместе отправят пару файлов, все прийдет корректно. Спасибо

Реализовал так:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("base")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories({"base.contracts.repository","base.edocs.repository"})
public class AppConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{



    @Bean
    public MailSenderThread getNewThread(JavaMailSenderImpl sender){
        return new MailSenderThread(sender);
    }



    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSenderImpl.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPort(567);
        javaMailSenderImpl.setUsername("*****@*******.ua");
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPassword("******");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        javaMailSenderImpl.getJavaMailProperties().setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        return javaMailSenderImpl;
    }
}
```

Отправка:

```
public class MailSenderThread implements Runnable {



    private JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl;
    private String to;
    private String docNum;
    private String startDate;
    private String fileName ;
    private byte[] file;

    ///инициируем сендер
    public MailSenderThread(JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl) {
        this.javaMailSenderImpl = javaMailSenderImpl;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(to+";" , ";,");
            MimeMessage message2 = javaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message2,true);
            Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
            formatter.format("Вам отправили № %S від: %s",docNum , startDate.substring(0,10));
            helper.setTo(tokenizer.nextToken());
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                helper.addCc(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            helper.setFrom("*****@********.ua");
            helper.setSubject(formatter.toString());
            helper.addAttachment(fileName, new ByteArrayResource(file));
            javaMailSenderImpl.send(message2);
        } catch (MessagingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


     public JavaMailSenderImpl getJavaMailSenderImpl() {
        return javaMailSenderImpl;
    }

    public void setJavaMailSenderImpl(JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl) {
        this.javaMailSenderImpl = javaMailSenderImpl;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getDocNum() {
        return docNum;
    }

    public void setDocNum(String docNum) {
        this.docNum = docNum;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@ComponentScan("services")
public class InfoController {
    @Autowired
    private Services services;
    @Autowired
    private UtilService utilService;
    @Autowired
    private MailSenderThread newThread;


    @RequestMapping("/user/sendFile/{contract}/{id}")
    public void sendFile(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("contract") long contract
            , @PathVariable("id") long id
            , Model model
        , @RequestParam String to) {
        try {
            try {
                Photos file = services.getPhotoByID(id);
                Contracts contracts = services.getContractByID(contract);
                System.out.println("file Size ------" + file.getBody().length);
                if (file.getBody().length < 22381002) {
                    /*utilService.sendMailFile(to, contracts.getDocNum(), contracts.getStartDate().toString()
                            , file.getName(), file.getBody());*/
                    newThread.setDocNum(contracts.getDocNum());
                    newThread.setFile(file.getBody());
                    newThread.setFileName(file.getName());
                    newThread.setStartDate(contracts.getStartDate().toString());
                    newThread.setTo(to);
                    new Thread(newThread).start(); // стартуем в другом потоке
                } else {
                    utilService.sendMailUrl(to, contracts.getDocNum(), contracts.getStartDate().toString(), file.getName());//шлем ссылку на дропбокс файл
                }
                response.sendRedirect("/user/info/contract/" + contract);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    model.addAttribute("error", "Не удалось отправить файл!");
                    response.sendRedirect("/user/info/contract/" + contract);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Правильнее при каждом входе в контроллер создавать обьект MailSenderThread  и его уже стартовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все уже придумано до вас. Для таких случаев существует `@Async` - [пример из документации](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).

Вы сразу возращаете пользователю  ответ, не заставляя его ждать окончания долгого запроса. А результат отправки после завершения операции сохраняете на сервере и периодически, незаметно для пользователя, опрашиваете его по таймеру черех AJAX.

---

> Я не совсем понимаю, если заходит 5 запросов на контроллер, то спринг
>   создает 5 экземпляров сервиса, или один? Если один, то как тогда
>   происходит паралельное выполнение всех 5-ти методом?

Когда вы помечаете метод аннотацией, которая требует от Spring определенной дополнительной работы, а не просто создания экземпляра класса, к таким, например, относятся `@Transactional`, `@Cacheable`, `@Async`, он создает обертку вашего класса - [прокси](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring). Прокси бывают разные и это отдельная тема. Через эту обертку происходит добавление необходимой логики.

Через прокси задача оборачивается в `Runnable` и передается в `Executor`. По умолчанию, используется [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java). Вы его подключили когда установили аннотацию `@EnableAsync` на одном из ваших классов конфигурации.

Это кратко. Если вам досконально интересна логика всего процесса, можете [посмотреть тесты Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/d5ee787e1e6653257720afe31ee3f8819cd4605c/spring-context/src/test/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation). В документации к [@EnableAsync](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) описано как добавить собственную реализацию `TaskExecutor`, если вас не устраивает текущая, а в [документации Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor-types) какие они вообще существуют.

Если обобщить, Spring в бэграунде делает все то же, что вы хотели делать вручную, только более гибко, по сути, предоставляя вам готовую инфраструктуру и возможность сочинять меньше кода.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал, получилось. Если не сложно, разъясните пжл как именно спринг обрабатывает это. Я создал отдельный сервис по отправке письма. в этом сервисе есть метод `sendMail` и он помечен анотацией `Async`. Я не совсем понимаю, если заходит 5 запросов на контроллер, то спринг создает 5    экземпляров сервиса, или один? Если один, то как тогда происходит паралельное выполнение всех 5-ти методом? Спасибо!

Comment: Не за что, обновил.